# How do I configure a producer and consumer in Kafka REST Proxy?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-rest

How do I set up a producer and consumer in Kafka REST Proxy?
If i use kafka-clients.jar and implement it in java, i can easily make all the settings.
acks, commit method, and so on.
I know that the basics can be set in confluent-4.1.1 / etc / kafka-rest.

acks, how to commit, etc. How can I configuration this?

References: https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/docs/config.html

Answer (score 0):

Commiting is done by POSTing the offsets you've gotten back from a previous consume request.

> `POST /consumers/(string: group_name)/instances/(string: instance)/offsets`
>
> Commit a list of offsets for the consumer. When the post body is empty, it commits all the records that have been fetched by the consumer instance.

I don't think acks can be set by a HTTP request

> Producer instances are shared, so configs cannot be set on a per-request basis. However, you can adjust settings globally by passing new producer settings in the REST Proxy configuration